# Perl Script, look at windows folder while executing on unix

Tags: perl, unix

I have a perl script that runs on a unix machine (Linux01) and does a variety of things. I want to add something to the script that will allow me to run a system command on a windows machine (Wdinows01) that is on my network that I have permission/access to.

I want to do something like this:

```
my $result = `cat \\Windows01\tmp\test\fileinfo.txt`;
```

Obviously the above code is missing a lot but, is this possible at all or is this more complicated then I think?

Comment: The example you showed is not a compelling reason to go to the trouble of executing commands on a remote system.  Why not just share the Windows drive with your linux system, mount the drive, and address it from your linux system? Then you're running the 'cat' command locally against a remote file system.

Comment: The machine will change periodically and will not be able to be hardcoded. Additionally, one of the restrictions of my script is I cannot mess with the system in any way (like mounting drives)

Comment: Running a command on a remote system *is* messing with it.  Running commands on arbitrary remote systems is one of the things the whole world of computer security strives to restrict.

Comment: That is a good point...

Comment: If you're unwilling to `mount` the remote share, have you considered accessing the share via `smbclient`?

Comment: Or have a look at [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/).

Answer (score 2):

Backticks follow the same coding rules as double-quoted strings, which means that

```
`...`
```

is the same thing as

```
readpipe(qq`...`)
```

So let's see the string you're passing to the shell:

```
$ perl -E'say qq`cat \\Windows01\tmp\test\fileinfo.txt`'
cat \Windows01  mp      est
ileinfo.txt
```

Oops! `\\` produces a backslash, `\t` produces a tab, and `\f` produces a form feed. Fixed:

```
my $result = `cat \\\\Windows01\\tmp\\test\\fileinfo.txt`;
```

(That's assuming your `cat` takes Windows paths.)

Comment: Or `my $result = qx'cat \\\\Windows01\tmp\test\fileinfo.txt'`

Comment: You *have* to escape multiple backslashes, as I'm sure you know

Comment: I think that's what *multiple* means

Comment: Please show the string represented with fewer backslashes

Comment: Ah I see what you're getting at. I think that's even more obscure.

Comment: @Borodin, It is. Like I said, it's awful and inconsistent. (Though doing it four times instead of three is not any more obscure.)